# get category with parent 0 in woocommerce rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am getting all categories by calling following function

```
$wc_api = new WC_API_Client( $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $store_url );
echo json_encode( $wc_api->get_categories());
```

which is calling following function

```
public function get_categories( $params = array() ) {
    return $this->_make_api_call( 'products/categories', $params );
}
```

I want to add condition or parameter like want to get categoris which have parent = 0 how can i get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve what you are wanting:

1.**Client side filtering** - you are already calling `get_categories` function, this will return all the categories which you can then filter on the client.

2.**Server side filtering** - you can use `woocommerce_api_product_categories_response` filter to modify the API output. Add the following code to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_api_product_categories_response', 'my_woocommerce_api_product_categories_response', 10, 3);

function my_woocommerce_api_product_categories_response( $product_categories, $terms, $fields ) {

    // add your code to do the filtering here    

    return $product_categories;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain about woocommerce_api_product_categories_response is it in built function ?which class i have to include for use of this function ?

Comment: Yes it is a filter provided WooCommerce. As mentioned just add the code in your theme's functions.php file and add the code you require. When a  a request is made to `get_categories`, WooCommerce will run that filter.

Comment: Is it still working, i tried adding this in my functions.php but it doesnot do anything

Answer (score 2):

I recently tried this and it actually worked so some who is looking for this solution right now, so i am answering this.

Just pass parent=0 parameter and you will only get parent categories

https://yourdomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?per_page=25&page=1&parent=0